# Add conditionally a key / value pair to an array in Woocommerce

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I would like just to add conditionally `'s' => $search_term` to an array if there is a search term.

```
$args = array(
    // if there is a $search_term then insert: 
   's' => $search_term 
);
```

I know that I can write many arguments and then using an if statement outside the array but that is way is not what am wishing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to do it outside the array as if not the key `'s'` will be declare anyway in the array (with an empty value if there is no a **search term**.

Try the following where we insert conditionally a new key / value pair in a defined array:

```
// Initialize (or define) the array variable
$args = array();

// IF + Condition
if( isset($search_term) && ! empty($search_term) ){
    // Inserting in $args array a new key / value pair
    $args['s'] = $search_term;
}
```

Or as explained before, with an always defined `'s'` key as follow:

```
$args = array(
    's' => isset($search_term) && ! empty($search_term) ? $search_term : '';
);
```

Comment: Thank you.I did go with this solution if( isset($search_term) && ! empty($search_term) ){
    // Inserting in $args array a new key / value pair
    $args['s'] = $search_term;
} . I appreciate your help

Comment: @AmjadKhalil You are welcome. Just to say that I have updated my 2nd code snippet as there was a little mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you propose cannot be accomplished. The PHP [array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) function is used to declare the keys and values. So, when you write:

```
$args = array( 
   's' => $search_term 
);
```

It will create the key 's'. You can do the following

```
$args = array( 
       's' => isset($search_term) ? $search_term : null
    );
```

and query with isset($args['s']) to do what you describe, but IMO it is bad to rely on that behavior. [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns false what array values are null.

The best way is as LoicTheAztec recommends, but you have your workaround here.